# jquery ajax call for asp.net mvc application getting two unauthorized reponses then Ok

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am executing the following jquery ajax call to an asp.net mvc controller which works, however on the firebug console it seems it is getting executed three times. The first two times it returns 401 Unauthorized and the final time it return 200 Ok. Could anyone shed some light on what is happening when I make this request and how I could stop the inital calls from failing.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Core/GetVariableSet',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function(response) {
        thisObject.Date = new Date(response.Date);
        thisObject.UserId = response.UserId;
        thisObject.UserName = response.UserName;
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        Util.errorhandling.AJAXError($('#main'), 
                       'Error Getting Variables',
                       XMLHttpRequest, 
                       textStatus, 
                       errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've seen this on .net apps before, too. I'd be interested to know what causes it.

Comment: I seem to recall this is down to how firefox/browsers sent validation: the first 401 says you need to valid, the second 401 is because the browser sends the validation wrong and then finally it sends it correctly and you get your 200.

Comment: I thought this might be the case but is there any way I can force this to authenticate correctly the first time? I am using NTLM for authenticating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this was happening to me when I was debugging in firefox.  The fix I found was to add the site to the 'network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris' list in firefoxs about:config.

Be sure to include the port if it's the local development server causing problems.

Comment: I think this answer is on the right track. I've seen these errors on Firebug when the asp .net app uses integrated windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say with out the context in which it is being executed. I.e. when the executions are done, and why it excutes three times.

The fact that it is being tried until the 200 is received makes me suspect that there is some sort of rety going on. Possibly something hasn't finished loading?

Have a read about the 401 error to see if this sheds any light on it for you.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html